# FireDac query not reading large integers correctly

Tags: delphi

I am trying to query a database using FireDac. Here is my code;

```
procedure TfSMSViewer.LoadSMSFromDatabase(path: AnsiString);
var
  con: TFDConnection;
  query: TFDQuery;
  LI: TListItem;
  B: Int64;
begin
 con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
  con.LoginPrompt := False;
  con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=' + Path +' ;');
  query.Connection := con;
  query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM sms';
  query.Open;
  query.First;
  While Not Query.EOF Do
  Begin
    LI := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LI.Caption := inttostr(query.Fields[4].AsLargeInt); //This line
    if query.FieldValues['type'] = 1 then
      LI.SubItems.Add('Incoming')
    else
      LI.SubItems.Add('Outbound');

    LI.SubItems.Add(query.FieldValues['address']);
    LI.SubItems.Add(query.FieldValues['body']);
    Query.Next;
  End;
end;
```

However the line highlighted doesn't work correctly. In the database, an example value set in this column is 1418421520957 (a UNIX timestamp).

When that line of code is executed, the result is 1082313277.

The data type in the SQLite database is set to Integer. The freeware software I'm using to debug this shows the correct value. When debugging my code, the incorrect value is pulled from the database before any assignment is made.

Also some of the values populated in my `TListView` are negated. 
[image: Values loaded into the listview from my code]

Does `TFDQuery` not support large integers? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of the database column itself? Does SQLite have a large integer data type? (IIRC, it does not.) It's hard to say why the values aren't what you'd expect if you don't explain what you have for data that you're querying against in the first place. When posting a question here, please remember we have absolutely zero information to use other than what you provide us; we can't read your mind or see your screen from where we're sitting.

Comment: The data type is set to Integer. The freeware software I'm using to view the database outside my application displays the value correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details there, instead of in comments. People can't easily see that information in the comment clutter.

Comment: Use e.g. the `INT64` data type for your SQLite column (to keep reading it by `AsLargeInt` as you do). FireDAC will then treat this [`pseudo-type`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types) as being 64-bit signed integer (`dtInt64` data type). I would optionally suggest you an unsigned 64-bit integer (`UINT64` type), but [`there is no`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TField_Properties) `AsLongLongWord` like property for it.

Comment: 1418421520957 is hex `0x14A4082CA3D`, and 1082313277 is hex `0x0004082CA3D`.  As you can see, the second value is the first value with its high 32bits truncated off.  So either your database column is using a 32bit data type instead of a 64bit data type (unlikely considering your freeware app displays the values correctly), or your FireDAC driver is not detecting the proper data type when populating the `TFDQuery.Fields` collection (such as by using `TIntegerField` instead of `TLargeintField`).

Comment: The value is correct but truncated to 32bit.

Comment: @TLama - I can't change the data type as the database is from Android.Is there any changes I can make to the driver settings to fix it?

Comment: Then create a `TLargeintField` field for that column *manually* (that's what I would prefer). Or you can make your own data type mapping (an example of how to map `INTEGER` type column to `dtInt64` data type field [`is here`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Adjusting_FireDAC_Mapping)).

Comment: I've just tried doing this, maybe I'm missing something? `i: TLargeIntField; i := TLargeIntField(query.FieldByName('date')); ` This still doesn't give the correct answer.

Comment: No, that is not correct. The field obtained by `FieldByName` must already be of type `TLargeIntField`. You need to explicitly create it somewhere (before you open the dataset). There are few ways how to do it. At design time e.g., it can be done through the fields collection editor (you can open it throught the query component's context menu).

Answer (score 5):

This is how I fixed it, with suggestions from TLama. Maybe this will be useful for someone, or my future self.

```
  con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
  with query.FormatOptions do begin
    OwnMapRules := True;
    with MapRules.Add do begin
      SourceDataType := dtInt32;
      TargetDataType := dtInt64;
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

'BIGINT' for your Database column can solve this problem